# Selenium IDE not executing code angular ng-click

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-ide

I've just started using Selenium IDE, I click on a button that loads a view and with-in that view `li` and the li has `ng-click='doSomething(myFunc)'` which runs a function that loads content.

**code:** 
 `<li ng-repeat="a in [1,2,3,4,5]" ng-click(myFunc)>{{a}}</li>`

When clicking through everything works fine. With Selenium it shows as being captured but wen I the test I get this error

`[info] Executing: |sendKeys | id=jsonform-1-elt-0.name | Simo |` (SIMO being the name typed in)

`[error] Element id=jsonform-1-elt-0.name not found`

NOTE: my form is built from a Json schema using https://github.com/Simomultimedia/jsonform

Any suggestions on what might cause selenium not to execute?

Comment: Have you tried "Selenium Builder"?

Comment: I haven't. Il look into it. Thanks.

Comment: Where did you come up with that id? That's what it is not finding. And from your small snippet of code, it's tough to tell what the DOM/HTML looks like that you're testing against.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using protractor? It has been developed specifically for testing end to end angularjs apps (by the angularjs team). https://github.com/angular/protractor

Its like selenium on steroids (uses webdriver behind the scenes).